# jQuery-Mask-Plugin validate date by regex pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So i'm trying to use jQuery-Mask-Plugin but the documentation its not very clear to me regarding validation. Meaning i'm trying to use the basic setup for a date input.

```
<input id="mydateinput" name="mydateinput" type="text"/>
$('.mydateinput').mask('00-00-0000');
```

This works fine but with this i can put a a date like so 99-99-9999 and i would like to restrict the date input like so 31-12-1700.

I do have this regex to validate the input:

```
var test = /(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-([12]\d{3})/;//dd-mm-yyyy
```

I would like to combine this regex with the plugin. But this doesn´t work, anyone with ideas ?

```
$('.mydateinput').mask('ZX-YK-0000',{
    translation: {
     'ZX': { pattern: /(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])/, optional: true },
     'YK': { pattern: /(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/, optional:true }
    }
});
```

[Jquery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: The problem is i can type a date like so 99-99-9999...

Comment: Why not use a `.match` instead of the `.mask`?

Comment: match ? I cant see that in documentation...